# Ruby with spreadsheet getting stuck on exceptions

Tags: ruby, exception

I have the following code:

```
require 'spreadsheet'

class MyObject
  def initialize
    @workbook = Spreadsheet::open('foo.xls', 'r')
  end
end

h = MyObject.new
h.inexistent
```

Running it, Ruby (1.9.2p290 [i386-mingw32]) will print "`test.rb:10:in '<main>'`", and then start continuously eating up RAM until it gets killed.

Obviously, this is the beginning of the exception message "`test.rb:10:in '<main>': undefined method 'inexistent' for #<MyObject:0xfb5140> (NoMethodError)`".

Without an exception being thrown, the program will terminate normally.

What could be causing this strange behaviour?

Note that `inexistent` does not exist. This is intentional in order to demonstrate the behaviour when an exception is thrown.

Comment: What version of the spreadsheet gem are you using?  How large is the xls file and was it created by the gem or via Excel?  Can you successfully load the file and view it using spreadsheet in irb directly?

Comment: @Kronos: It is 0.6.5.9 (the most recent one). The XLS is smallish, created with Excel. I can successfully load and read in Ruby (script or irb) -- as long as no exception is raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a shot in the dark:

I believe the answer to your problem is that when the exception is thrown the spreadsheet object is being converted into its string representation, and this makes even a small spreadsheet take up a large amount of memory temporarily.

I couldn't reproduce your ever growing memory, but in my case even with a 22k spreadsheet I was able to make irb consume about 140 megs of ram before it stabilized back by inspecting the spreadsheet object.

A simple way to test this is to add a custom to_s method for your MyObject which avoids the spreadsheet dump.

```
class MyObject
  def initialize
    @workbook = Spreadsheet::open('foo.xls', 'r')
  end
  def to_s
    "Put something more useful here"
  end
end
```

Comment: Well shot -- that's it. Thanks a lot.